# Caching API responses in .NET Core

Tags: .net, ajax, caching, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm building a website that will have a feature that if you hover over an object, a special div will be filled with ajax with details on the object.

Since the client side isn't really that important, I'll just say that there's jquery hover event on certain elements that trigger ajax `.load()` with `https://api..../GetDetails/*Id*` url and that function will fetch the item details via EntityFramework and the View will be something like

```
@model Details

<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
```

(again, simplified because it's not the point).

But with the growing userbase, and the fact that a person can just swipe their mouse around like a madman, I figured that not caching this would create a problem with the traffic flow.

Is it possible, and if it is, how can I cache the responses so that

`https://api..../GetDetails/ABC` always returns the same thing without doing all the math behind and that `https://api..../GetDetails/DEF` does not return ABC but it's cached as well?

Comment: It just occured to me that I technically could use scheduler like HongFire on the server so that it creates a folder filled with html information for each item and that the links on the web just refer to that file instead of the actual api call..

Comment: I think if you use jQuery .load method it will cache it so only a single network request is made per page load.  I would test it out with browser developer tools opened and see how many network requests are sent to your endpoint.

Comment: there'd be a plenty of calls that I'm sure of.. moving objects from one side to another (jquery ui droppable) for it for verification purposes.. I can name quite a few ajax calls to get json data + the stuff I talk about here on hover

Answer (score 4):

In ASP.NET Core, you can use Response Caching. It will let us add cache related headers to the response. These headers determine how client, proxy or the middleware cache the responses. 
Refer to the documentation [ASP.NET Core Response Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response)

It's an extensive feature which can be used to determine the cache location, duration and invalidating cache based on request header values. You can even create cache profiles for different scenarios.
Some samples are as below

1.Cache by duration

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 60)]
public IActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

    return View();
}
```

2.Set the cache location

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 60, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client)]
public IActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

    return View();
}
```

3.Vary the response cache by request header

```
[ResponseCache(VaryByHeader = "User-Agent", Duration = 30)]
public IActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

    return View();
}
```

4. Create Cache profiles in Startup

   ```
   services.AddMvc(options =>
   {
       options.CacheProfiles.Add("Default",
           new CacheProfile()
           {
               Duration = 60
           });
       options.CacheProfiles.Add("Never",
           new CacheProfile()
           {
               Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None,
               NoStore = true
           });
   });
   ```
5. Use cache profiles as needed

   ```
   [ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Default")]
   public IActionResult Index()
   {
       return View();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use IMemoryCache (or any other caching service) or Cache Tag Helper.

**IMemoryCache**

First, register it:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMemoryCache();
}
```

Then inject it into your controller:

```
private IMemoryCache _cache;

public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    _cache = memoryCache;
}
```

And cache your model:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
{
    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(id, out Details cachedDetails))
    {
        cachedDetails = await GetDetailsAsync(id);

        var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
           .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

        _cache.Set(id, cachedDetails, cacheEntryOptions);
    }

    return View(cachedDetails);
}
```

**Cache Tag Helper**

In your view you can use something like this:

```
@model Details

<cache vary-by-route="id">
    <h1>@Model.Name</h1>
</cache>
```